# Telerik angular2 Grid Template switch

Tags: angular, telerik-grid

I'm trying to generalize making Telerik Grid with angular2. in my component.ts I have:

```
 private cols: Column[] = [
    { name: 'id', desc: 'ID' },
    { name: 'listen', desc: 'Listen' },
    { name: 'station', desc: 'Station' },
    { name: 'location', desc: 'Location' },
    { name: 'type', desc: 'Type' },

];
```

and getting the data correctly (I tried without case and is working correctly)
then in my template html:

```
<kendo-grid [data]="gridPager">
<template *ngFor="let col of cols" let-col>
</template>
</kendo-grid>
```

I'd like to apply a different processing for each column. how can I apply ngSwitch in this case after the ngFor Template. I tried several way like adding `<span [ngSwitch]="col.name", {{"col.name"}}`or

```
<template *ngFor="let col of cols" let-col>
        <kendo-grid-column [ngSwitch]="col.name">
            <template *ngSwitchCase="'listen'" kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-column>
                <button kendoButton (click)="open(dataItem)" style="width:180">{{dataItem.station.text}}</button>
            </template>
            <template *ngSwitchDefault kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-column>
            </template>

        </kendo-grid-column>
    </template>
```

but for no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I finally Found the way, and posting for others.

```
<template ngFor [ngForOf]="cols" let-col>
        <kendo-grid-column field="{{col.name}}" title="{{col.desc}}" [ngSwitch]="col.name" [sortable]="col.name!='listen'">
            <template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-column *ngSwitchCase="'listen'">
                <button kendoButton (click)="open(dataItem) " style="width:180">{{dataItem.station.text}}</button>
            </template>
            <template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem let-column *ngSwitchCase="'station'">
                <a href="{{dataItem.station.href}}" target="_new">{{dataItem.station.text}}</a>
            </template>
        </kendo-grid-column>
    </template>
```